# строки DOM таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Есть вот такой скрипт, по нажатию кнопки, создает строку таблицы, возможно ли сделать чтобы генерируемый  имел ввид  к примеру. Суть в том чтоя не могу подцепится другим скриптом к этой строке.

```
function addContact ()
{
var tb = document.getElementById ('contacts'),
    ro = tb.insertRow (-1);


NUMS = (!self.NUMS) ? 1 : ++NUMS;
var ce = ro.insertCell (0), inp = document.createElement ('div');
inp.innerHTML  =  NUMS; ce.appendChild (inp);
inp.className = ('drag');
inp.id ="Dialog" + NUM;
inp.style.background ='red';

var ce = ro.insertCell (-1), inp = document.createElement ('input');
inp.name = 'name' + NUMS; ce.appendChild (inp);

var ce = ro.insertCell (-1), inp = document.createElement ('input');
inp.name = 'text' + NUMS; ce.appendChild (inp);

var ce = ro.insertCell (-1), inp = document.createElement ('input');
inp.name = 'status' + NUMS; ce.appendChild (inp);

}
```

Проблема в том что свойство срабатывает и все ставится, но как добитсы trstyle1, trstyle2.... для каждой строки

```
ro.className = ('trstyle') ;
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно.